# Why can't extract number in a string with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I can extract port number in the string:

```
s="2017-04-17 08:16:14 INFO     connecting lh3.googleusercontent.com:443 from 111.111.111.111:26215"
echo $s  | sed  's/\(.*\):\(\d*\)/\2/'
26215
```

Almost the same knowledge,i want to extract number following "#" in a string:

```
s="alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor/#4"
echo $s | sed   's/\#\([0-9]\)/\1/'
alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor/4
echo $s | sed   's/#\([0-9]\)/\1/'
alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor/4
```

Why the output is not the number "4" ?

Comment: You need to consume the whole line with `.*` (in many cases, `.*` is also required on the right). The main thing here (when you need to keep a part of a line) with `sed` is to match the whole line that will be replaced with the captured value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're substituting "#4" with "4", but not changing the front part of the string.  In your first example, the ".*" is gobbling up the first part.  By analogy:

```
echo $s | sed 's/.*\#\([0-9]\)/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider `gnu-grep` then it is easier with:

```bash
s="alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor/#4"
grep -oP '(?<=#)\d+' <<< "$s"

4
```

Or using `awk`:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /#[0-9]+/) {print substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)}' <<< "$s"

4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only removing the `#` hash character but retaining everything else as it is not included in the match. You could just remove everything up to and including the hash.

```
$ sed 's/.*#//' <<< "$s"
4
```

If back referencing must be used, you can use;

```
$ sed -E 's/.*#([0-9]+)/\1/' <<< "$s"
4
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> echo "alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor/#4" | 
>
> mawk ++NF OFS= FS='^.*#|[^0-9]*$'
> ```

```
4
```

If you know only numbers at the tail after `#` then even simpler :

> ```
> gawk '$_ = $NF' FS='^.+#'
> ```

```
4
```